# Half space and positive combination

Tags: linear-algebra

This a exercise from Artin Algebra.

> Let V be a Euclidean space of dimension n, and let $S = (v_i, . . . , v_k)$ be a set of vectors in V. A positive combination of $S$ is a linear combination $p_1v_1+...+ p_kv_k$ in which all coefficients p, are positive. The subspace $U = \{v|(v, w) = 0\}$ of V of vectors orthogonal to a vector w is called a hyperplane. A hyperplane divides the space V into two half spaces $\{v|(v, w) > 0\}$ and $\{v| (v, w) < 0\}$.
>
> (a) Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> S is not contained in any half space.
>
> For every nonzero vector w in V, $(v_i, w) < 0$ for some $i = 1, . . . , k$.
>
> (b) Let S' be the set obtained by deleting $v_k$ from S. Prove that if S is not contained in a half space, then S' spans V.
>
> (c) Prove that the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) S is not contained in a half space.
>
> (ii) Every vector in V is a positive combination of S.
>
> (iii) S spans V and 0 is a positive combination of S.
>
> Hint: To show that (i) implies (ii) or (iii), I recommend projecting to the space U
> orthogonal to $v_k$. That will allow you to use induction.

I already prove the $(a),(b),(c) (ii)\iff(iii)$  and  $(ii) \implies(i)$

For $(i)\implies(ii)$ flowing the hint. To induction in dimensions. For n = 1, it is obvious.
Assuming for $n-1$ is true. To prove $n$ is true.

I already prove if S is not contained in a half space in V that S$'$ is not contained in have space in $u_k^\bot$.

The problem is I cannot find out a positive combination for $-u_k$

Comment: duplicate to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403717/stiemke-s-theorem-from-farkas-lemma-or-gordan-s-theorem